# Crossfilter Row Chart Top 10

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, dc.js

I'm trying to return a Top 10 list using Crossfilter.js D3.js and DC.js and display in a row chart.

HTML file points to js file where the code resides as follows:

```
var Chart8 = dc.rowChart("#rChart8", "group1");

var People = ndx.dimension(function (d) {return d.datPeople;});
var People_Grp = People.group().reduceSum(function (d) { return d.datVal; });

Chart8.width(300)
                .height(530)
                .margins({top: 20, left: 10, right: 10, bottom: 20})
                .transitionDuration(750)
                .dimension(People)
                .group(People_Grp)
            .colors(ColourSet1)
                .renderLabel(true)
                .gap(1)
                .title(function (d) { return ""; })
                .elasticX(true)
            .xAxis().ticks(8).tickFormat(d3.format("s"));
```

Can anyone help to filter this to show only the Top 10 by Value (datVal) ?
I have tried with ".top(10)" but am obviously missing something.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I managed to get there in the end.

Added a variable for the number of results:

```
selTop = 10
```

Then passed this to group.top:

```
Chart8.data(function (group) { return group.top(selTop);});
```

Using the variable (10) also allows me to dynamically size the height of the chart:

```
.height(selTop * 23)
```

Sorted